# optimize sqlite database image

Tags: performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

Im using a sqlite database.

Inside a table there is a blob field. Is there any lazy attribute I can use to optimize the query since I don't need the blob image every time the row is selected ?

Answer (score 1):

I would store the image blobs in a separate table altogether, using a hash of the image as a key. The image can then be referenced from other tables using said key.

One immediate benefit is that storing duplicates can be easily avoided. Each time you're about to insert an image you check if the hash-value, calculated from the image data, already exists in the image table. If it exists, you simply insert a reference to that row elsewhere. If it doesn't exist, you insert the image blob, including the corresponding hash-key, and use that key elsewhere to reference the image.